# How-to create 'packages gitlab-ce repository mirror in Artifactory'

Tags: repository, artifactory

I use Artifactory Version 6.5.0
I couldn't create a mirror for https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce repository. The Official Documentation recommends to use at apt-mirror utility. Yes, It works. I want to have the mirror in Artifactory.

I found a solution. URL for remote repository in Artifactory has name https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce
Name doesn't include OS Linux.(for example Debian, Ubuntu etc)
I set type is Debian.
Sources list will be:
deb [arch=amd64] https://artifactory.example.com/gitlab-ce-deb-remote/ubuntu/ xenial main
It is example.
I resolved this problem, closed.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to answer and accept your own response so other developers can learn from it.